# Outer product as string?

Tags: python, matlab, numpy

I am trying to do the following. The outer product of an array [a,b; c,d] with itself can be described as a 4x4 array of 'strings' of length 2. So in the upper left corner of the 4x4 matrix, the values are aa, ab, ac, ad. What's the best way to generate these strings in numpy/python or matlab?

This is an example for just one outer product. The goal is to handle k successive outer products, that is the 4x4 matrix can be multiplied again by [a,b; c,d] and so on.

Comment: In Matlab it's very easy, but there's a minor problem: the array `['aa' 'ab']` (for example) is the same as `['aaab']`. So the final result would be a 8x4 char array. Alternatively, the result could be generated to be a 4x4x2 array, where the strings are read along the 3rd dim. What do you want the result to be?

Comment: that's fine. what's your solution?

Comment: Shouldn't your (1-D) array be represented as `[a;b;c;d]` instead of `[a,b;c,d]`. What you have represented is a (2-D) matrix.

Comment: As I said, it depends on how you want the result: 8x4 or 4x4x2. You tell me

Comment: To handler successive products, define the problem to take 2 arrays or lists, `foo(A,B)`, where `A` and `B` can have different sizes (e.g. 4x4 and 2x4).  `foo(foo(A,A),A)` would be the 2nd successive.

Comment: How should `foo(foo(A,A),A)` differ from `foo(A, foo(A,A))`?

Answer (score 5):

You can obtain @Jaime's result in a much simpler way using `np.char.array()`:

```
a  = np.char.array(list('abcd'))
print(a[:,None]+a)
```

which gives:

```
chararray([['aa', 'ab', 'ac', 'ad'],
       ['ba', 'bb', 'bc', 'bd'],
       ['ca', 'cb', 'cc', 'cd'],
       ['da', 'db', 'dc', 'dd']],
      dtype='|S2')
```

Comment: Cool! I tried `np.add.outer(s, s, dtype='S2')` on an `S1` dtype array and it returned `NotImplemented`, had forgotten about this.

Answer (score 2):

Using a funky mix of `itertools` and `numpy` you could do:

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> s = 'abcd' # s = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'] works the same
>>> np.fromiter((a+b for a, b in product(s, s)), dtype='S2',
                count=len(s)*len(s)).reshape(len(s), len(s))
array([['aa', 'ab', 'ac', 'ad'],
       ['ba', 'bb', 'bc', 'bd'],
       ['ca', 'cb', 'cc', 'cd'],
       ['da', 'db', 'dc', 'dd']],
      dtype='|S2')
```

You can also avoid using numpy getting a little creative with `itertools`:

```
>>> from itertools import product, islice
>>> it = (a+b for a, b in product(s, s))
>>> [list(islice(it, len(s))) for j in xrange(len(s))]
[['aa', 'ab', 'ac', 'ad'],
 ['ba', 'bb', 'bc', 'bd'],
 ['ca', 'cb', 'cc', 'cd'],
 ['da', 'db', 'dc', 'dd']]
```

Comment: Thanks but this isn't quite an outer product, the answer should be ['aa', 'ab', 'ba', 'bb'],['ac', 'ad', 'bc', 'bd'], ['ca', 'cb', 'da', 'db'],['cc', 'cd', 'dc', 'dd']]. The order of the letters in each string is not important though.

Answer (score 1):

You could use list comprehensions in Python:

> ```
> array = [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']]
> flatarray = [ x for row in array for x in row]
> outerproduct = [[y+x for x in flatarray] for y in flatarray]
> Output: [['aa', 'ab', 'ac', 'ad'], ['ba', 'bb', 'bc', 'bd'], ['ca', 'cb', 'cc', 'cd'], ['da', 'db', 'dc', 'dd']]
> ```

Comment: thanks! I am afraid this doesn't generalize to higher number of outer products? I edited my question above. What do you think?

Comment: Generalizing to `[[y+x for x in flatA] for y in flatB]` produces a (16,4) 'array' on the 2nd application.  E.g. `[[aaa,aab,aac,aad,aba,...]...]`.  Is this what you want?

Comment: yes! almost, except that the (16,4) array should be square, just like in outer products, so it should be reshaped into (8,8) array.

Comment: I can reshape the `(16,4)` into a `(4,4,4)` that makes sense, but not a `(8,8)`.

Comment: [['aaA', 'aaB', 'abA', 'abB', 'baa', 'bab', 'bba', 'bbb'],['aaC', 'aaD', 'abC', 'abD', 'bac', 'bad', 'bbc', 'bbd'],[]...]. Basically note that the capitalized letters form blocks if you were two look at this list of lists as a 8x8 numpy array.

Answer (score 0):

To continue the discussion after Jose Varz's answer:

```
def foo(A,B):
    flatA [x for row in A for x in row],
    flatB = [x for row in B for x in row]
    outer = [[y+x for x in flatA] for y in flatB]
    return outer

In [265]: foo(A,A)
Out[265]: 
[['aa', 'ab', 'ac', 'ad'],
 ['ba', 'bb', 'bc', 'bd'],
 ['ca', 'cb', 'cc', 'cd'],
 ['da', 'db', 'dc', 'dd']]

In [268]: A3=np.array(foo(foo(A,A),A))
In [269]: A3
Out[269]: 
array([['aaa', 'aab', 'aac', 'aad', 'aba', 'abb', 'abc', 'abd', 'aca',
        'acb', 'acc', 'acd', 'ada', 'adb', 'adc', 'add'],
       ['baa', 'bab', 'bac', 'bad', 'bba', 'bbb', 'bbc', 'bbd', 'bca',
        'bcb', 'bcc', 'bcd', 'bda', 'bdb', 'bdc', 'bdd'],
       ['caa', 'cab', 'cac', 'cad', 'cba', 'cbb', 'cbc', 'cbd', 'cca',
        'ccb', 'ccc', 'ccd', 'cda', 'cdb', 'cdc', 'cdd'],
       ['daa', 'dab', 'dac', 'dad', 'dba', 'dbb', 'dbc', 'dbd', 'dca',
        'dcb', 'dcc', 'dcd', 'dda', 'ddb', 'ddc', 'ddd']], 
      dtype='|S3')

In [270]: A3.reshape(4,4,4)
Out[270]: 
array([[['aaa', 'aab', 'aac', 'aad'],
        ['aba', 'abb', 'abc', 'abd'],
        ['aca', 'acb', 'acc', 'acd'],
        ['ada', 'adb', 'adc', 'add']],

       [['baa', 'bab', 'bac', 'bad'],
        ['bba', 'bbb', 'bbc', 'bbd'],
        ['bca', 'bcb', 'bcc', 'bcd'],
        ['bda', 'bdb', 'bdc', 'bdd']],

       [['caa', 'cab', 'cac', 'cad'],
        ['cba', 'cbb', 'cbc', 'cbd'],
        ['cca', 'ccb', 'ccc', 'ccd'],
        ['cda', 'cdb', 'cdc', 'cdd']],

       [['daa', 'dab', 'dac', 'dad'],
        ['dba', 'dbb', 'dbc', 'dbd'],
        ['dca', 'dcb', 'dcc', 'dcd'],
        ['dda', 'ddb', 'ddc', 'ddd']]], 
      dtype='|S3')
```

With this definition, `np.array(foo(A,foo(A,A))).reshape(4,4,4)` produces the same array.

```
In [285]: A3.reshape(8,8)
Out[285]: 
array([['aaa', 'aab', 'aac', 'aad', 'aba', 'abb', 'abc', 'abd'],
       ['aca', 'acb', 'acc', 'acd', 'ada', 'adb', 'adc', 'add'],
       ['baa', 'bab', 'bac', 'bad', 'bba', 'bbb', 'bbc', 'bbd'],
       ['bca', 'bcb', 'bcc', 'bcd', 'bda', 'bdb', 'bdc', 'bdd'],
       ['caa', 'cab', 'cac', 'cad', 'cba', 'cbb', 'cbc', 'cbd'],
       ['cca', 'ccb', 'ccc', 'ccd', 'cda', 'cdb', 'cdc', 'cdd'],
       ['daa', 'dab', 'dac', 'dad', 'dba', 'dbb', 'dbc', 'dbd'],
       ['dca', 'dcb', 'dcc', 'dcd', 'dda', 'ddb', 'ddc', 'ddd']], 
      dtype='|S3')
```

Comment: Thanks for posting this! So basically reshape each line of the (4,4,4) array into a 2x2 square which goes into an 8x8 array. if this makes sense.

Comment: thanks! This is still not quite right though. See my comments below for the exact arrangement. if you do : B = A3.reshape(32,2); C = np.vsplit(B, 16) then each of the 2x2 blocks need to be arranged in an 8x8 matrix

Comment: See my other answer - inspired by the Kronecker product.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that you want the Kronecker product of two char.arrays?

A quick adaptation of `np.kron` (numpy/lib/shape_base.py):

```
def outer(a,b):
    # custom 'outer' for this issue
    # a,b must be np.char.array for '+' to be defined
    return a.ravel()[:, np.newaxis]+b.ravel()[np.newaxis,:]

def kron(a,b):
    # assume a,b are 2d char array
    # functionally same as np.kron, but using custom outer()
    result = outer(a, b).reshape(a.shape+b.shape)
    result = np.hstack(np.hstack(result))
    result = np.char.array(result)
    return result

A  = np.char.array(list('abcd')).reshape(2,2)
```

produces:

```
A =>

[['a' 'b']
 ['c' 'd']]

outer(A,A) =>

[['aa' 'ab' 'ac' 'ad']
 ['ba' 'bb' 'bc' 'bd']
 ['ca' 'cb' 'cc' 'cd']
 ['da' 'db' 'dc' 'dd']]

kron(A,A) =>

[['aa' 'ab' 'ba' 'bb']
 ['ac' 'ad' 'bc' 'bd']
 ['ca' 'cb' 'da' 'db']
 ['cc' 'cd' 'dc' 'dd']]
```

`kron` rearranges the `outer` elements by reshaping it to `(2,2,2,2)`, and then concatenating twice on `axis=1`.

```
kron(kron(A,A),A) =>

[['aaa' 'aab' 'aba' 'abb' 'baa' 'bab' 'bba' 'bbb']
 ['aac' 'aad' 'abc' 'abd' 'bac' 'bad' 'bbc' 'bbd']
 ['aca' 'acb' 'ada' 'adb' 'bca' 'bcb' 'bda' 'bdb']
 ['acc' 'acd' 'adc' 'add' 'bcc' 'bcd' 'bdc' 'bdd']
 ['caa' 'cab' 'cba' 'cbb' 'daa' 'dab' 'dba' 'dbb']
 ['cac' 'cad' 'cbc' 'cbd' 'dac' 'dad' 'dbc' 'dbd']
 ['cca' 'ccb' 'cda' 'cdb' 'dca' 'dcb' 'dda' 'ddb']
 ['ccc' 'ccd' 'cdc' 'cdd' 'dcc' 'dcd' 'ddc' 'ddd']]

kron(kron(kron(A,A),A),A) =>

# (16,16)
[['aaaa' 'aaab' 'aaba' 'aabb'...]
 ['aaac' 'aaad' 'aabc' 'aabd'...]
 ['aaca' 'aacb' 'aada' 'aadb'...]
 ['aacc' 'aacd' 'aadc' 'aadd'...]
 ...]
```